# Why is plt.errorbox giving me continuous graph when I just want data in dots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I'm using errorbox in matplotlib to plot a graph in which

```
x1 = (0, 100, 60, 20, 80, 40)
y1 = (0.0, 0.058823529411764705, 0.058823529411764705, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

plt.figure()
plt.errorbar(x1, y1)
plt.title("Errors")
plt.show()
```

This would give me continuous lines instead of separate 6 data points? 
How can I fix it to just yield 6 data points? I tried using 'o' as the 3rd argument for pet.errorbar(x1,y1, 'o').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following properties:

```
plt.errorbar(x1, y1,ls='None', marker = 'o')
```